# Play two sound together on two button touch using soundpool

Tags: android, multi-touch, soundpool

I am trying to play two sound together when two button is touch together at the same time. I have button1 and button2, while button1 is touch, button2 wont play the sound. But when I put my finger off button1 then touching button2 plays the sound.

I have tried googling around but couldn't find an answer. 
What I wanted to do is clear. Play two sound together when two buttons are touch together.

Below is my code so far.

```
public class MultitouchtestActivity extends MultiTouchActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;

SoundPool soundPool;
AudioManager audioManager;
int soundId;
int kID, sID;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.getWindow().clearFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    //the maximum number of simultaneous streams for this SoundPool object
    int maxStreams = 4;
    //the audio stream type as described in AudioManager
    int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
    //the sample-rate converter quality. Currently has no effect. Use 0 for the default.
    int srcQuality = 0;

    soundPool = new SoundPool(maxStreams, streamType, srcQuality);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(soundPoolOnLoadCompleteListener);
    soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c, 1);
    kID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.k, 1);
    sID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.s, 1);

    btn1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                float vol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float leftVolume = vol/maxVol;
                float rightVolume = vol/maxVol;
                int priority = 1;
                int no_loop = 0;
                float normal_playback_rate = 1f;
                soundPool.play(kID,
                        leftVolume,
                        rightVolume,
                        priority,
                        no_loop,
                        normal_playback_rate);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                float vol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float leftVolume = vol/maxVol;
                float rightVolume = vol/maxVol;
                int priority = 1;
                int no_loop = 0;
                float normal_playback_rate = 1f;
                soundPool.play(sID,
                        leftVolume,
                        rightVolume,
                        priority,
                        no_loop,
                        normal_playback_rate);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener soundPoolOnLoadCompleteListener =  new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status)
    {
        if(status==0)
        {
            btn1.setEnabled(true);
            btn2.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MultitouchtestActivity.this,"SoundPool.load() fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

}

```
public class MultiTouchActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private View parent;

public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
{
super.onCreate(instance);
parent = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
parent.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

for (int ptrIndex = 0; ptrIndex < event.getPointerCount(); ptrIndex++) {

    // index of the pointer which starts this Event
    int actionPointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

    // resolve the action as a basic type (up, down or move)
    int actionResolved = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    if (actionResolved < 7 && actionResolved > 4) {
    actionResolved = actionResolved - 5;
    }

    if (actionResolved == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

    dealEvent(ptrIndex, event, v, actionResolved);
    Log.v("tag", "move" + ptrIndex);

    } else {
    dealEvent(actionPointerIndex, event, v, actionResolved);
    }
}
return false;
}

private void dealEvent(int actionPointerIndex, MotionEvent event,
    View eventView, int actionresolved) {
int rawX, rawY;
int location[] = { 0, 0 };
eventView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
// Log.v("tag", location + "");
rawX = (int) event.getX(actionPointerIndex) + location[0];
rawY = (int) event.getY(actionPointerIndex) + location[1];

ArrayList<View> views = getTouchedViews(rawX, rawY, actionresolved);

// dumpEvent(event);
for (View view : views) {
    int x, y;
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    x = rawX - location[0];
    y = rawY - location[1];
    // Log.v("tag", "touched" + view.toString());
    /*
     * view.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(event.getDownTime(),
     * event.getEventTime(), event.getActionMasked(), x, y,
     * event.getMetaState()));
     */
    // MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
    MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(event.getDownTime(),
        event.getEventTime(), actionresolved, x, y,
        event.getPressure(actionPointerIndex),
        event.getPressure(actionPointerIndex),
        event.getMetaState(), event.getXPrecision(),
        event.getYPrecision(), event.getDeviceId(),
        event.getEdgeFlags());
    me.setLocation(x, y);

    // Log.v("tag", "oldeventid: " + event.getAction() + " #" +
    // actionPointerIndex+ " id" + ptrId+ " resolved "+ actionResolved);
    // Log.v("tag", "neweventid: " + me.getAction() + " #" +
    // actionPointerIndex+ " id" + ptrId+ " resolved "+ actionResolved);

    if (!me.equals(event)) {
    /*
     * Log.v("tag", "actionindex: " + actionPointerIndex +
     * " resolved: " + actionPointerIndex + " to " + view.toString()
     * + " y:" + view.getTop() + "-" + (view.getTop() +
     * view.getHeight()));
     */
    // me.setAction(actionresolved);
    view.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    if (actionresolved == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    Log.v("tag",
        "#" + actionPointerIndex + "Rawx:" + rawX + " rawy:"
            + rawY + "x:" + x + " y:" + y + " "
            + view.toString());
    }
}

}

private ArrayList<View> getTouchedViews(int x, int y, int action) {

int moveGap = 0;

if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    moveGap = 0;
}

ArrayList<View> touchedViews = new ArrayList<View>();
ArrayList<View> possibleViews = new ArrayList<View>();

if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
    possibleViews.add(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < possibleViews.size(); i++) {
    View view = possibleViews.get(i);

    int location[] = { 0, 0 };
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    if (((view.getHeight() + location[1] + moveGap >= y)
        & (view.getWidth() + location[0] + moveGap >= x)
        & (view.getLeft() - moveGap <= x) & (view.getTop()
        - moveGap <= y))
        || view instanceof FrameLayout) {

        touchedViews.add(view);
        possibleViews.addAll(getChildViews(view));
    }

    }
}

return touchedViews;

}

private ArrayList<View> getChildViews(View view) {
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    ViewGroup v = ((ViewGroup) view);
    if (v.getChildCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
        views.add(v.getChildAt(i));
    }

    }
}
return views;
}
```

}

Comment: please help any comment is appreciated abundantly

Comment: please help 
 
 
please help any comment is appreciated abundantly